# error on altering table column type in postgresql - bigint to character varying

Tags: postgresql, alter

Below is the query:

```
alter table customer_master alter column pk_customer_id type character varying(20);
```

I got the following error message:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying > integer HINT:  No
>   operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_master(
  pk_customer_id bigint NOT NULL,
  created_customer_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  fk_deployment_id bigint NOT NULL,
  is_active integer
 )
```

here `pk_customer_id` is the *primary key column* for this table.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

[`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html) as per documentation:

> The optional USING clause specifies how to compute the new column
>   value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as
>   an assignment cast from old data type to new. A USING clause must be
>   provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new
>   type

```
ALTER TABLE customer_master
ALTER COLUMN pk_customer_id type CHARACTER VARYING(20) 
USING pk_customer_id::VARCHAR; -- add using keyword
```

Comment: this worked for me. thanks. and the issue was not only the query. There was a constraint which checks pk_customer_id field is > 0. so on removing constraint it worked for me.